# How to programmatically make an embedded video player play in fullscreen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the [Embedded Video Player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player) to add a video to a website. The video is contained within a small container. Therefore, I would like to provide alternative UI for starting the video in a fullscreen mode.

How to programmatically start video in an embedded video player in fullscreen?, i.e. equivalent to user hitting "Fullscreen" button on the video player itself.

Comment: I just found the API documentation. Looks like there are no controls for making the video play in fullscreen. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api